# Getting certificate details of an Intune managed device via Device ID

Tags: azure, powershell, intune

I'm new to Intune and a N00B at PowerShell.. Currently trying to get the Certificate info of a device managed by Intune by using the device ID. Relevent documentation has been hard to find..

My question is, how do I display info about a Device certificate and see info such as SubjectName, OrderNumber and more using PowerShell with a deviceID?

Steps taken so far:

1. Connected with "Connect-MgGraph" successfully
2. Get-MgDevice -DeviceId 'xxxxxxxxx' successfully
3. ???

SCEP profile is setup and works as intended towards the PKI.The devices are getting certs and are able to connect to 802.1x

Answer (score 0):

Install and import `Microsoft.Graph.Intune module` using below commands:

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Intune
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Intune
```

Try executing the below script to get the intune managed devices certificate information as shown:

```
connect-Mggraph
$device = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -deviceId "<DeviceID>"
$certificates = Get-IntuneManagedDeviceCertificate -DeviceId $device | select thumbprint, device //Select for the required fields
```

*Connected successfully:*

[image]

*Search for Intune in Azure Portal and it will redirect you to below page.*

[image]

*Check for the commands in Microsoft Intune using below command:*

`Get-Command -Module Microsoft.Graph.Intune`

[image]

[Reference](https://powershelladministrator.com/2021/12/07/get-list-of-intune-managed-devices/)